# Open a Windows cmd shell and run commands

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, shell, cmd

I'm working on a small project, and I need the usage of a Windows Shell with networking commands, that will turn on if a boolean value is true, and output the commands output to a listbox. I got it to open a cmd shell, but it is extremely limited and cannot run networking commands such as `arp`, `netview`, `nbtstat`, etc.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim A, IP As String
Dim B, C As Integer

...

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    B += 1
    IP = TextBox1.Text & "." & TextBox2.Text & "." & TextBox3.Text & "." & B
    A = My.Computer.Network.Ping(IP)
    If A = True Then
        'Process.Start("CMD", "/K nbtstat -a" & IP) NEEDS TO RUN AS A REAL CMD SHELL

    End If
    Text = "Pinging:" & IP
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, IP & " " & A)
    C = B / 30 * 100
    If B = TextBox4.Text Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
...

End Class
```

That is the small portion of code that handles the input.

Thrown error:

> 'nbtstat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> D:\Karanbir Ahuja\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NBTScan_Alpha.1\NBTScan_Alpha.1\bin\Debug>

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqWtN.jpg

Comment: Why can't you run networking commands? What error/(s) do you get and if no exceptions are thrown, what is your output?

Comment: You need to explain your problem thoroughly. We have absolutely no idea what happens when you run this code, nor exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Also, you're missing a space here: `"/K nbtstat -a" & IP`, it should be: `"/K nbtstat -a " & IP`.

Comment: I get a canned shell that says the command does not exist. Am going to take screenshots now.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/qynyC     OR: 'nbtstat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NBTScan_Alpha.1\NBTScan_Alpha.1\bin\Debug>  @VisualVincent

Comment: That's odd. What happens if you type it in manually?

Comment: @VisualVincent The generic Command does not exist. This occurs in VB 2010 and 2016. Typing in help reveals no NBTSTAT or ARP or any commands I need.

Comment: That is not Visual Basic's fault. It's Windows who owns CMD, not VB.

Comment: Have you tried the commands with CMD set to the `C:\Windows\System32` folder?

Comment: @VisualVincent Tried  Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\CMD.exe", "/K nbtstat -a " & IP) and I got the same error

Comment: That does not change anything. CMD exists in System32, but specifying the absolute path does not set the working directory. You need to call the `cd C:\Windows\System32` command before `nbtstat`, like so: `"/K cd C:\Windows\System32 & nbtstat -a " & IP`.

Comment: @VisualVincent http://prntscr.com/efs431 That was my result, not sure if I did that right. Haven't done much with shell in VB. Same error as before.

Comment: Since the folder didn't change from `D:\Karanbir Ahuja\...` it quite obviously didn't work (although I don't get why, it should've worked). Try this instead: http://pastebin.com/EWB8gyYK

Comment: @VisualVincent It changed the Directory to system32, but nbtstat does not work. Same old "command is not recognized".   http://prntscr.com/eg26jd

Comment: I forgot the `/K` flag, yes. -- As for the command, I have no idea why it doesn't work for you. I've looked around at Google but I couldn't find anything useful... Best you can do (since this question isn't actually programming related any longer) is to ask a question about _that specific issue_ on a forum that specializes on computers in general. [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) is one option and is part of the Stack Exchange network, just like Stack Overflow.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help anyways. I thought it was a machine issue but I've tested this on multiple machines. I think it might be a windows 10 issue now, nevertheless, I'm asking over there.